Any solution for Windows scrollbar 'snapback' effect?
Before deciding to ask here I really searched the whole Internet without luck and since a long time, but this topic strangely enough seems "taboo", despite so evident and frustrating. It plagues all versions of Windows since XP and likely earlier versions AFAIK...
When I refer to "jumping scrollbars" (literally: "crazy" scrollbars) I refer to standard system scrollbars, which suddenly jump to their initial position if dragged too much over their final position. This affects every program, from the File Explorer to text editors to audio editors to graphics programs (unless they are using custom GUI toolkits), and affects both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. Anyone can verify this simply with an Explorer window or the Notepad.
I suspect it is a bug and not a "feature", because this behavior honestly makes no sense, it is very annoying and I don't think anyone could ever want it at design level. For example, in the past it happened to me to write a scrollbar gadget class, and I simply clamped its position from zero to the useful max as anyone would do, so I really cannot explain this choice other than as an actual bug. But what I judge incredible is that at Microsoft they never realized it and/or never did anything to fix it !!!
So my question: is there any way or trick to fix this bug ? Maybe with some hidden Registry value ? Or maybe there is some third party "hack" or "patch" to fix it ? Keep in mind that this bug is unrelated to the mouse, to the hardware or gfx card used. It affects all Windows setups as far as I can witness.
EDIT: later (and not without efforts !) I realized that this "bug" is rather popularly known as "snapback", so I have also changed the title accordingly. And, standing to some, it would rather be a "feature". This topic was risen only once on stackexchange:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/55623/why-do-scrollbars-revert-to-original-scroll-distance-when-mouse-is-dragged-sidew
but in that case the question was quite ambiguous: "Is there any benefit or explanation for this behaviour from a UX point of view?". My question instead is if any solution, including "hacks" or third party utilities, is known or available.

Really! I noticed It too but i thought it was just me and instead It happens also to other users... Let's hope there Is a patch or tool outthere to fix this problem!

Well I am ready to pay a coder for a patch. I would also make a gift to the community, since such a thing does not exist yet. I suspect it is about patching a system dll. Just, I have no idea where to start from, any site where one can offer such bounties ?

I can find some forum questions and answers searching for: "windows scrollbar snapping back" but indeed no one has a fix for this other than 3rd party solutions.

Are you aware of any such 3rd party solutions ? I could find none...

I found a possible 3rd party "solution" under this forum post: link - dude talks about using AutoHotKey to intercept the scrollbar movement? - Looks like using something like autohotkey could work. but it seems a bit of an unstable fix so i didnt mention it at first.

unfortunately that does not seem a very practical trick...
